# How to fix yarn ios build error in React Native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, build, yarnpkg

When I run:

```
yarn ios
```

it throws this error:

```
The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/applemacbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-dqnlgtsougxpuwdghrmclyntrevj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-1FA6E1255725D37983E4E9DE0E0B6F29.sh
(1 failure)

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

[image: Error Image]